# Processing data with different schema

Tags: python, pyspark, data-science, data-analysis, databricks

I am using Azure Databricks's AutoLoader.

I have blob storage with lots of JSON files. Those consists of a few dozen of different schemas.

The current solution is based on inferring the schema and saving the data into  Delta Tables. However, as the number of Tables and JSON schemas increases it starts to become hard to control. In case of any error, the whole importing process stops.

I am thinking about creating separate autoLoader per every Schema but I am struggling with finding any article that would make me sure that it is a valid approach.

Please let me know what your thoughts are, is having 30-40 writeStreams accessing single blob storage a valid approach?

I am just starting in data analysis topic, so I would appreciate even the most obvious suggestions.